# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using Laravel 9, ReactJs with vite js

Tags: laravel, npm, vite

I'm trying to build an app using Laravel 9 and ReactJS with vite js. I tried following command to build.

> npm run dev

But I'm getting following errors,

> GET http://[::1]:5173/resources/css/app.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

> GET http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

> GET http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/app.jsx net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

> GET http://[::1]:5173/@react-refresh net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I got this too, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I developed the same app with Laravel 10 and got no error.

Answer (score 53):

If you entered `npm run build` on production, your `.env` file looks good, and you still have such errors as the author – just delete the file `public/hot`.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, this solved the issue for me deploying from local to docker container into DO App Platform. It was driving me absolutely nuts!

Comment: Legend! You saved my deploy. I tried literally anything to fix this problem. I even thought it was because of my webhost.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer!

Comment: It is simple solution, awesome! I would like to give your answer 20 votes)))

Comment: Weird, I have no idea why this worked but thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

For those using Laravel Sail, open the `vite.config.js` file and configure it like so:

```
export default defineConfig({

  plugins: [
    react(),
    laravel({
        input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
        refresh: true,
    }),
  ], 
  server: {
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
    },
  }
});
```

If need be, stop and restart the server `sail npm run dev`

Answer (score 4):

Its Work for me
1-First Run `npm run dev` in Terminal
2-Then Run `npm run build`

Comment: Seriously, Didn't know that, we have to first do this step before building. Also one more thing, we have to set the ASSET_URL to the live domain.

Answer (score 3):

If you have run `npm run dev` then you must find a file in `public/hot` and Rewrite the proper address / URL in it. For me `http://127.0.0.1:5173` worked.

Answer (score 2):

This means that your assets are not built yet, use `npm run build`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found a solution with the build option called Rollup.
When building in production, rollup will remove unused code. In this process it will bundle the required assets and reference them in accordance to the URL that you would be using at that current moment.

To fixed it, you could try this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
      build: {
        rollupOptions: {}
      }
    })
```

I was helped by a similar issue posted on Github so maybe you could use that as a point of reference.
[Here is the Discussion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/8689)

Answer (score 1):

add `host` in your `vite.config.js`, so it will force it to IPv4

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',  // Add this to force IPv4 only
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the port 5173 was already in use.
I've just freed it - and everything worked again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '10.10.x.30',  // Add this to force IPv4 only
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Chrome extensions you have enabled. In my case, it was "uBlock Origin" that was messing with vite dev server